# What do the diagonal lines in these circuits mean?

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

What exactly do these diagonal lines represent in these circuits? (I have them circled in red.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What exactly do these diagonal lines represent in these circuits? (I
> have them circled in red.)*

The diagonal line and its associated number tells you the number of connections so, `/10` means ten connections i.e. it is defining the width of bus.

Comment: But, why have they been made above the OR gates in the second figure?

Comment: @theCursedPirate you'd have to provide a link to the document to stand a chance of figuring that out. Not all people writing documents are 100% consistent either.

Comment: Because there is up to 8 inputs to the or gates.